# Filter a List of string in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings

```
List<string> str = new List<string>
str.Add("test1");
str.Add("test2");
str.Add("test3");
```

After some processing this list goes to some service where the list gets modified and can have any of the three values "test1"," test2", "test3" or all of them.

I want to **filter** this list based on the strings: "test1"," test2", "test3" and dump it into some another object.

How do I filter it without giving hardcoded string values?

How do I do it in C# using Linq?

Comment: Have you tried anything? `Where()` ? What does `filter this list based on the strings: "test1"," test2", "test3"` mean anyway? The list already contains those values. What is the expected result?

Comment: How do I do it without giving hardcoded string values?

Comment: `var someVar = "your search string"; bool listContains = str.Contains(someVar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am understanding you 100%, but if you need to see if the elements of the list contains sequences of characters look up the LINQ Contains. If you need an example look here: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/linq-contains-method/

I am using a Db below but the idea is kinda the same but the syntax is similar. I think I had to change it into an IQueryable first.

Make a Method with this approach, but instead of e.NewTextValue put your search String as an input or whatever, this is my XF example:

```
var searchList = strList.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()) || 
                x.CategoryName.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()) || x.Comments.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()) ||
                x.SKU.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
```